# ehCache 3.0 default on-heap entries size (used with hibernate 2nd level cache)

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache, jcache

I have hibernate 2nd level cache enabled with ehcache 3.0 implementation. I am running into an issue where the cache hits are relatively fast on around 10k entries, and very slow on around 30k entries. The slowness is not linear, which makes me suspect that the entries are being stored off-heap or on disk. I also validated that by taking stacktraces and seeing the serializer as the bottleneck (while on-heap should not use serializers to my knowledge). I did not add an ehcache.xml config file. I seem to be running on default settings. Any idea what is the default heap size for ehcache?

Answer (score 0):

> The slowness is not linear, which makes me suspect that the entries are being stored off-heap or on disk.

You would need to configure such behavior. Nobody can give a detailed advice without knowing your configuration or program.

From the information you provided, most likely cause:

By increasing the cache size your program needs more heap memory. If the used heap memory gets close to the available heap memory, your program slows down because of excessive garbage collection. The garbage collector needs "breathing space" to run efficiently.

My general approach for any performance issue:

- Learn about the maximum heap size of your used Java implementation
- Use your OS tools to see what is currently going on and get an idea of the resource usage of your program, in terms of memory, CPU and I/O. On Linux that would be `vmstat`
- Use a tool like visualvm or turn on the GC logs to see the garbage collector activity
- Have a reproducible test that you can use for the performance evaluation

To find an ideal heap and entry size, I suggest:
Run the test with 5k entries. How much memory is claimed by your Java application? How much memory is available in the system?
Run the test with 10k entries. Answer the same question. Then you can linearly predict the amount of memory with other cache sizes.